# How to get the maximum Z-Index of multiple elements (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a bug and do not seem to find a solution that satisfies my senior dev. I have the following problem:

I have a dashboard where the user can drag and drop multiple elements into it and set them the way he wants. Now, whenever a new element is dragged into the dashboard, its z-index gets set to 'auto' and it appears behind the other elements. I want to get the highest z-index available on the dashboard.

I already have written a function that gets me the highest z-index just fine, as you can see below.

```
function getZIndexOfElementAndAddOne() {
  let temp = -1;
  $('.elementIwant').each(function() {
    let zIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
    while (temp <= zIndex) {
      temp++;
   }
```

However, my senior dev tells me that it consumes to many resources and that I should swap the while loop with an if statement like so.

```
function getZIndexOfElementAndAddOne() {
  let temp = -1;
  $('.elementIwant').each(function() {
    let zIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
    if (temp <= zIndex) {
      temp++;
   }
```

But if I actually do that, the function does not return me the z-indexes of the elements but instead something else I don't even know what it is.

I would be really glad if someone could help me with this. Even an advice on how to approach the problem another way is more than welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getZIndexOfElementAndAddOne() {
  const newElement = document.querySelectorAll(".newElement")[0];
  const aElements = document.querySelectorAll(".elementIwant");
  let temp = -1;
  aElements.forEach(el => {
    let zIndex = parseInt(el.style.zIndex);
    if (temp <= zIndex) temp = zIndex + 1;
  });
  newElement.style.zIndex = temp;
  console.log("Z-Index new element: " + newElement.style.zIndex);
}

getZIndexOfElementAndAddOne();
```

```html
<div class="newElement"></div>
<div class="elementIwant" style="z-index: 1;"></div>
<div class="elementIwant" style="z-index: 2;"></div>
<div class="elementIwant" style="z-index: 100;"></div>
<div class="elementIwant" style="z-index: 50;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without doing an iteration loop, I think you can combine both CSS and JS. Here's what I would attempt to solve your ticket.

The idea is, whenever a new element is being added / dragged or whatever, you should have something UNIQUE to specific it. I'd suggest adding a CSS class like `current-item` or something like that to the element.

Once the element is added into the DOM tree, CSS will shine with this simple selector:

```
.whatever .item.current-item {
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Notice that this approach utilizes the `!important` flag that most jQuery or js lib use to override the styling of a DOM element. Here we're using it to make sure it will be the highest element, of course, when there's no item being dragged/added, the CSS won't apply.

You can even easily toggle the state of any DOM with something like `$('.item').toggleClass('current-item')` in jQuery.

I hope this approach would satisfy your "Senior Dev", the mindset behind this is based on the state of an item, and the DOM will reflect this state, the same like React guys do.

Update:
- My suggestion is to try your best to inspect the "new element", if it already has its unique CSS class, then re-use this class. Otherwise, try to add a specific class for this "new element" and proceed

Comment: Hi, @Duc Hong, I will give it a shot. Let's see if it works.

Comment: Your suggestion was a really good one. By adding a new class to the elements and combining it with the solution of alexP I could get it to work really nicely. Thanks a lot mate!